NPM Module @githubnext/github-copilot-cli fails to authenticate
I am trying to install and use the npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/@githubnext/github-copilot-cli. The npm module github-copilot-cli fails to complete authentication.
The github-copilot-cli auth command fails with a Http status 502 repeatedly.
I installed the npm module @githubnext/github-copilot-cli through the below command
npm install -g @githubnext/github-copilot-cli
It completes the installation successfully.
I then try to authenticate the CLI using the command below,
github-copilot-cli auth
I get a message stating,
Copy this code: <>
Then go to https://github.com/login/device, paste the code in and approve the access.
I copy the code and go to the URL and paste the provided code and then approve the CLI.
after which it waits for few seconds and displays the below error.
Failed to authenticate: Request failed with status code 502, <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

I tried this multiple times and facing the same problem, I am not behind any proxy. Any help is appreciated!

same issue here, any one found a solution?
